# Tampering TCP data on a Windows application

Tags: windows, networking, tcpip

Is there an application where I can run another application and it will allow me to see and more important manipulate the TCP data sent to another server?

I'm using Wireshark to view the data, but I want to alter it on the fly. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is the tool for that job, you just have to configure your application to use a proxy and you can then modify requests on the fly.

edit:
I assumed you were talking about HTTP but if you want to do the same thing with any TCP traffic have a look at those tools:
[Hatkit](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Hatkit_Proxy_Project)
[ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is this only for web content? the requests I want to manipulate are not web requests..

Comment: @user122926 - TCP packets are TCP packets....http traffic is tcp traffic.  How about try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called netsed to achieve this.

http://www.freshports.org/net/netsed/

I have used this on linux . The syntax for replacement with regular expression is same as "sed" tool but i think all the functionality of sed is not there in netsed.

On Windows you might have to run it with Cygwin.